# Understanding the contents of a library in C

Tags: programming, library, c, atmega328

So this is a question not just about the #include  but most all includes you find while programming in C.

So I understand a library is prewritten code and when you include that library are you able to used certain function that are included in that library.

What I have always wanted to know is: where can you find the "instruction set", in C, for these libraries?

How can I find out what commands are available for me to use with this library?

hope this makes sense.

thank you everyone.

Comment: A library provides an Application Program Interface (API) and the API should be documented with the library somewhere, but the quality of that documentation varies depending on the library.  Maybe https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Libraries is a place to start?

Comment: `where can you find the "instruction set", in C, for these libraries?` Libraries come with either binary or source files. You should include the header file (.h or .hpp) in this file you can find the function definitions along with (usually) comments.
If you have a implementation file (.c or .cpp) these will have the (C/C++) source code available.

Answer (score 2):

> What I have always wanted to know is: where can you find the "instruction set", inc C, for these libraries?

The libraries are usually found in the `libraries` sub-folder under your sketchbook folder (wherever that is). There is also another `libraries` folder inside the IDE install folder for the "official libraries".

> How can I find out what commands are available for me to use with this library?

Usually the library documents them in one way or another. Try looking inside the `.h` file used by the library to see what functions are exposed.